# Pass string array as image source

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to pass an array of string values to be concatenated onto a URL address to create an inline-block of images.
I have the following:

```
          <div className="row text-center">
            { this.state.sketchs.map((sketch, key) => {
              return(
                <div key={key} className="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div className="token" img src={{ 'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/' : sketch }}></div>
                  <div>{sketch}</div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
```

The css file has the following:

```
.token {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I am successful in pushing the array "sketch" into "token" shown below highlighted in blue.

[image: App Block of images]
But I want the highlighted blue "hash" to be used as the img source with 'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/' at the beginning of each one.

How would I go about achieving this? Why is my code not working above? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your URL is an object, it needs to be a string. `{'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/' + sketch}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your markup of `img` is right:

```
 <div className="row text-center">
            { this.state.sketchs.map((sketch, key) => {
              return(
                <div key={key} className="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div className="token">
                     <img src={'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/' + sketch }>
                   </div>
                  <div>{sketch}</div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have put the `<img />` tag in the wrong place.

Try to use backticks `` and concatenate the string like this:

`` <img src={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${sketch}`} /> ``

with backticks around the src link and the concatenated string.